# Can a server configured with one Firebase project send notifications to an individual user of an app in a different project?

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native, react-native-firebase, react-native-fcm

I am using Firebase with React Native. There are two different projects with one Android app under each project.

My backend server is configured to receive/store the FCM token of every individual app user. Right now, the same backend server caters to both apps. The FCM json config file for the backend server is based on *one* of the aforementioned two projects.

Can the backend send notifications to an user of either of the two apps, as long as it has their FCM token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this so long as it comes from the respective apps FCM credentials, this prevents abuse and FCM hijacking. this does not mean that you need cloud functions on multiple projects as you can manually instantiate new admin-sdk modules to connect and send FCM messages as needed.

- Initiate Multiple Apps: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize-multiple-apps

A side note to consider: You may also be interested in registering the FCM if your app has multiple projects as only the default app is registered with normal behaviour.

- [FirebaseMessaging.getInstance(firebaseApp) for secondary app supposed to be public but it's private?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62253691/firebasemessaging-getinstancefirebaseapp-for-secondary-app-supposed-to-be-publ/65863769#65863769)

Comment: Ok, I will try this out.

Comment: I think it is quite doable to have two separate config files and messaging instances on the backend server. Maybe I'll just do that instead to keep things clean.

Comment: sounds perfect! just note that you can't access cloud function triggers from outside of it's origin project. but everything else with the admin-sdk will work fine.